# Como hago para hacer la suma de los productos que yo selecciono

Tags: javascript, html, array, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

estoy haciendo una simulacion de un Ecommerce y no logro hacer la suma de los productos que yo selecciono, logre almacenar los nombres de los productos en mi carrito pero la verdad no se como seguir con esto, probe haciendo unos class para almacenar mis productos pero el codigo no me compilaba, busque soluciones por todos lados pero estoy muy trabado con esto

```
/* Variables Globales */
let total = 0;
let cantCarrito = '';
let sumaCarrito = 0;
let ver = 0
let suma = 0;

/* Carrito */
let carrito = [];
```

Aqui creo mi funcion principal donde se va a ejecutar la mayor parte del codigo

```
function listadoProductos(){
   let cantidad = 0;
   let precio = 0
   let compra = 0; 
   let listado = Number(prompt('Listado de productos y precios \n1) Cajas de madera - $650 c/u 
\n2) Cajas de madera personalizadas - $950 c/u \n3) Tazas - $450 c/u \n4) Bolsas - $500 c/u 
\n5)Estampados remeras - $1200 c/u \n6)Estampados buzos - $2200 c/u \n7)Mousepads - $750 c/u'))

switch(listado){
    case 1 : alert('Usted elegio Cajas de madera')
             cantidad = Number(prompt("Cuantas desea llevar?"));
             carrito.push('Cajas de madera')
             precio = 650;
             total = calcularCostoTotal(precio, cantidad);
             cantCarrito = verCarrito(carrito)
             alert(`Ustede tiene en su carrito: ${cantCarrito}`)
             compra = Number(prompt('\nQuiere agregar mas cosas al carrito? \n1)Si \n2)No'))
             if( compra == 1 ){
                nuevoCarrito = [...carrito, cantCarrito]
                verCarrito()
                listadoProductos()
             }else{
                nuevoCarrito = [...carrito, cantCarrito]
                alert(`Total a pagar: $${total} `)
                confirmacionPago();
             }
             
             break;

    case 2 : alert('Usted elegio Cajas de madera personalizadas');
             cantidad = Number(prompt("Cuantas desea llevar?"));
             carrito.push('Cajas de madera personalizadas')
             precio = 950;
             total = calcularCostoTotal(precio, cantidad);
             alert(`Ustede tiene en su carrito: ${cantCarrito}`)
             compra = Number(prompt('\nQuiere agregar mas cosas al carrito? \n1)Si \n2)No'))
             if( compra == 1 ){
                nuevoCarrito = [...carrito, cantCarrito]
                verCarrito()
                listadoProductos(carrito)
             }else{
                nuevoCarrito = [...carrito, cantCarrito]
                alert(`Total a pagar: $${total} `)
                confirmacionPago();
             }
             break;
Habian mas CASE pero fueron borrados para que no haya tanto codigo por aqui
    
    default : alert("Opcion Erronea"); break;

 }

}
```

Calculo el costo total con un solo producto seleccionado

```
function calcularCostoTotal(precio, cantidad){
    total = precio * cantidad
    return total;
}

function verCarrito(carrito){
    console.log(carrito)
    return carrito
}
/* FIN CONJUNTO DE FUNCIONES PARA LA SELECCION DEL PRODUCTO */
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco porque usas prompt, supongo que estas experimentando.

Yo, lo primero que haría sería crear una estructura a modo de base de datos, así:

```
const Datos = [
{
  nombre : "Cajas de madera",
  precio: 650
},
{
  nombre : "Cajas de madera personalizadas",
  precio: 950
},
{
  nombre : "Tazas",
  precio: 450
},
{
  nombre : "Bolsas",
  precio: 500
},
{
  nombre : "Estampados remeras",
  precio: 1200
},
{
  nombre : "Estampados buzos",
  precio: 2200
},
{
  nombre : "Mousepads",
  precio: 750
}
];
```

Tambien una función para buscar un producto al array, recuerda que el indice del array comienza en cero, por lo que el primer producto es 0, el 2do es 1, etc.

```
function GetProducto(seleccion) {
        if (Datos.length >= seleccion) {
            return Datos[seleccion - 1];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Luego un par de funciones para imprimir el primer prompt

```
function GetStringProducto(producto){
  return producto.nombre + " - $" + producto.precio + " c/u";
}
function GetListaProductoString(){
    var lista = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
        lista += `${i+1}) ${GetStringProducto(Datos[i])}\n`;
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Después el carrito y su lógica:

```
let Carrito = {
    Productos : [],
    GetTotal: function() {
        let suma = 0;
        for (let p of this.Productos) {
            suma += p.precio * p.cantidad;
        }
        return suma;
    },
    Agregar: function(producto, cantidad) {
        this.Productos.push({ ...producto, cantidad: cantidad });
    },1
    Vaciar: function() {
        this.Productos = [];
    }
}
```

Donde tenemos:

- Productos: Un array para almacenar los productos
- GetTotal: Una función que retorna el total del carrito
- Agregar: Función que agrega un producto y la cantidad
- Vaciar: Para vaciar el carrito

Por último la función principal que es listar productos:

```
function listadoProductos(){
    let listado = Number(prompt(GetListaProductoString()));
    let producto = GetProducto(listado);
    if (producto != null) {
        cantidad = Number(prompt("Cuantas desea llevar?"));
        Carrito.Agregar(producto, cantidad);

        compra = Number(prompt('\nQuiere agregar mas cosas al carrito? \n1)Si \n2)No'))
        if( compra == 1 ){
            listadoProductos();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(`Total a pagar: $${Carrito.GetTotal()} `)
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Opcion Erronea");
        listadoProductos();
    }
}
```

Aquí te dejo el código completo

```js
const Datos = [
{
  nombre : "Cajas de madera",
  precio: 650
},
{
  nombre : "Cajas de madera personalizadas",
  precio: 950
},
{
  nombre : "Tazas",
  precio: 450
},
{
  nombre : "Bolsas",
  precio: 500
},
{
  nombre : "Estampados remeras",
  precio: 1200
},
{
  nombre : "Estampados buzos",
  precio: 2200
},
{
  nombre : "Mousepads",
  precio: 750
}
];

let Carrito = {
    Productos : [],
    GetTotal: function() {
        let suma = 0;
        for (let p of this.Productos) {
            suma += p.precio * p.cantidad;
        }
        return suma;
    },
    Agregar: function(producto, cantidad) {
        this.Productos.push({ ...producto, cantidad: cantidad });
    },
    Vaciar: function() {
        this.Productos = [];
    }
}
function GetStringProducto(producto){
  return producto.nombre + " - $" + producto.precio + " c/u";
}
function GetListaProductoString(){
    var lista = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
        lista += `${i+1}) ${GetStringProducto(Datos[i])}\n`;
    }
    return lista;
}
function listadoProductos(){
    let listado = Number(prompt(GetListaProductoString()));
    let producto = GetProducto(listado);
    if (producto != null) {
        cantidad = Number(prompt("Cuantas desea llevar?"));
        Carrito.Agregar(producto, cantidad);

        compra = Number(prompt('\nQuiere agregar mas cosas al carrito? \n1)Si \n2)No'))
        if( compra == 1 ){
            listadoProductos();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(`Total a pagar: $${Carrito.GetTotal()} `)
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Opcion Erronea");
        listadoProductos();
    }
}
    function GetProducto(seleccion) {
        if (Datos.length >= seleccion) {
            return Datos[seleccion - 1];
        }
        return null;
    }
    listadoProductos();
```